# What is the default expiration of presigned s3 URL created with boto3

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3, pre-signed-url

Here I am not giving any expiration while generating the URL. So how long will my URL be valid?

```
        client = boto3.client('s3',
              region_name=settings.BUCKET_NAME,
              aws_access_key_id=settings.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID,
              aws_secret_access_key=settings.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY,
              config=BotocoreClientConfig(signature_version='s3v4'))

        # generate signed post dictionary - also set the post url to be publicly readable
        post = client.generate_presigned_post(
                Bucket=settings.BUCKET_NAME,
                Key=key_name, Fields={'acl':'public-read'},
                Conditions=[{'acl': 'public-read'}])
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With the usage of `boto3.client.generate_presigned_post()`, the default expiration would be 1 hour since that is what [boto3](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.generate_presigned_post) sets by default:

> generate_presigned_post(Bucket, Key, Fields=None, Conditions=None, **ExpiresIn=3600**)